# How to console.log each comment and reply?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Im making a commenting system. People can comment. And people can reply to comments. In the mysql picture

[The two pictures are the same thing. In my yellow writing. comment[0].. should actually be comments[0].. and all others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43lVO.png)

***If you are wondering. In the bottom picture...***

**reply_id** if Null means the comment has no replies.

**parent_comment_id:** matches the comment_id. This means that the reply_comment 
                   replied to that comment of the comment_id Sorry for bad explantion.

**=========What I want===========**

First comment.

I replied to the first comment.

This is my second reply.

Brah...

get rekt kid.

**What I tried. Not working. Im bad at Javascript. I got 
"comment is not defined" error. My try is a bad example but just to give you a look on what im trying to do**

```
 for(var i = 0; i < comments[0].length; i++) { 
     if(comments[0][i].reply_comment && comments[0][i].comment == comments[0][i+1].comment || comments[0][i].comment != comments[0][i-1].comment ) { 
         console.log(comments[0][i].comment) 
         console.log(comments[0][i].reply_comment)
     } 
     else {
        console.log(comments[0][i].reply_comment)
     } 
}
```

Comment: look at your first `if` condition

Comment: I am willing to bet it is ```comments[0][i+1]```. You could check and see what this value is before the if statement to see if it's value is ```undefined```

Comment: oh I forgot to put the for loop in

Comment: No....you are missing an `s` from your first `if` condition. `comment[0][i].reply_comment` should be `comments[0][i].reply_comment`

Comment: `if(comment[0][i]` missing `s`. You might want to look at TypeScript at some point. It helps you prevent these types of mistakes.

Comment: Ok that worked. But now I added a reply to one of the comments and now it is saying "Cannot read property 'comment'" of undefined again

Answer (score 1):

The person who posted this might have already fixed this issue. Posting this answer to be helpful for the people who reads this question now.
In this code you have forgot to **check the existence of comments[0][i-1] and comments[0][i+1] array items**.
when the `i=0` you try to get the `comment` of the `comments[0][-1]` array item as `comments[0][i-1]` which is definitely not available.
Same thing applies to the other end as well. If array length is `5`, when `i=4` you will try to get the `comment` property of non-existing `comments[0][5]` as the `comments[0][i+1]`.
To fix this kind of issues you should check the existence of the array item first as below.
I just check the `comments[0][i]` element as well to be sure that the element is defined before using. If you are sure at that, you can skip that check.

```js
for(var i = 0; i < comments[0].length; i++) { 
     if(comments[0][i] && comments[0][i+1] && comments[0][i-1] &&
        comments[0][i].reply_comment && 
        comments[0][i].comment == comments[0][i+1].comment || 
        comments[0][i].comment != comments[0][i-1].comment ) { 
         console.log(comments[0][i].comment); 
         console.log(comments[0][i].reply_comment);
     } 
     else {
        console.log(comments[0][i].reply_comment);
     } 
}
```